# Discord.js v13 awaitMessages not working properly

Tags: discord.js

I have a guildMemberAdd event which whenever a user joins a server, it runs this code:

```js
const msg = await member.send('hi')
const filter = message => message.content === "e"

msg.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] }).then(c => {
    console.log("pog")
}).catch(e => console.log("Failed!"));
```

Although, whenever I reply to the bot with "e", it does absolutely nothing, and after the 10 seconds have passed, it logs "Failed!" in the console.

What am I doing wrong here? There are no error outputs in the console either from execution of the code above.

Comment: Have you tried removing the first line? And adjust `msg.channel.awaitMessages` to `message.channel.awaitMessages` instead - I suspect the `await` in line 1 is causing `awaitMessages` to fail.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I managed to fix it. The await was needed, after all, I was just missing the "DIRECT_MESSAGES" intent which I had no idea existed.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved, feel free to post an answer to your own question and mark it as the answer for anyone else who stumbles upon this in the future!